# Returning total sum of value for each month. VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to produce a total value for each month of the year from a generated report. Data is split into colunms one with a value you the other with a date.
I need to return a total for each month.

Data is output as such:

```
 100   21/01/2019
 200   21/06/2019
 150   01/01/2019
 300   14/09/2019
 8     08/05/2019
```

I need it to return as

```
  1  2 3 4 5  6  7 8  9  10 11 12
 250 0 0 0 8 200 0 0 300 0  0  0
```

With a further column for the following year. The original data and dates can be removed as this can be reproduced when running the next report.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), might help you to improve your question.

Comment: Just toss it into a pivot and stick your dates in the "columns" and your values into the "values" section and you'll be golden. No reason to right code for this one or pull out any fancy formulas and lookup tables.

Comment: @erazorv4 Understood thank you, with this one I felt as if I was banging my head against a wall.

Comment: @JNevill Thanks I have been able to fit this in to the existing report data. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below:

Add a helper column next to you date to get the month of the date:

```
=MONTH(B3)
```

and use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($C$3:$C$7=F2)*($A$3:$A$7))
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Can I ask why you use a relatively complex `SUMPRODUCT`, rather than just `SUMIFS($A$3:$A$7,$C$3:$C$7,$F2)`?

Comment: for some reason i find `sumproduct` more easier to use

Comment: Fair enough. Each to their own. I just wondered if there was a significant performance difference that I wasn't aware of.